# How to Search User by usernames in Cognito using Flutter App

Tags: flutter, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have built a app in Flutter using AWS Amplify. I have my user stored in Cognito. I have to build a feature where I can search users using usernames.

I saw many online solutions and even tried ChatGpt but couldn't find any accurate answer.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ListUsers.html

Comment: Can you share an example